# Save data on Close/Restart PC in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, settings

How can I save my data from textboxes so when I restart, the computer data still exists?

I know the method by using : databases and settings.  I added it through settings but when I restart my pc the data is gone.

Code:

```
Private Sub form1_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
    My.Settings.txt1 = TextBox1.Text
    My.Settings.txt2 = TextBox2.Text

End Sub


Private Sub form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    TextBox1.Text = My.Settings.txt1
    TextBox2.Text = My.Settings.txt2
End Sub
```

Comment: did you add `txt1` and `txt2` entries to Settings?  is App Framework active or did you Save and Load them yourself?

Comment: Depends also on how the computer is restarted. If you shutdown the power or if all program are properly closed.

Comment: FormClosed might be too late...FormClosing happens before the form is closed while the objects still exist

Comment: @Plutonix yes i added txt1 and txt2 to Settings as strings. If i open/close application it save's data. But if i close the application and restart the computer then the data is lost.

Comment: what about the other points/questions?

Comment: You should save your settings when modified. I don't remember the syntax in VB.Net but should be something like: `My.Settings.SaveChanges()`

Comment: You need to call My.Settings.Save or else they won't be saved.

Comment: @Mr CodeXor , this is still not working and won't load even when i do all planned can you please take review of my code. It's not long [Notepad.cc](http://notepad.cc/xuthaufru71)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub form1_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
My.Settings.txt1 = TextBox1.Text
My.Settings.txt2 = TextBox2.Text
My.Settings.Save()
End Sub


Private Sub form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    TextBox1.Text = My.Settings.txt1
    TextBox2.Text = My.Settings.txt2
End Sub
```